# How to check if user press the button? telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Easy task, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I'd like to check if user press the button 'Add variants' to add next messages from user to list `variants`. I tried to do it using `if message.text == 'Add variants'`, but it just adds to list text 'Add variants' one time and that's it. Is there any way to check if user click the button and after that add next messages from user to list?

```
variants = []

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'welcome'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Random')
    item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('TradingView')
    item_3 = types.KeyboardButton('Weather')
    item_4 = types.KeyboardButton('Other')
    item_5 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
    markup.add(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):

    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Random':
            
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Add variants')
            item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
            markup.add(item_1, item_2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup = markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'welcome'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Random')
    item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('TradingView')
    item_3 = types.KeyboardButton('Weather')
    item_4 = types.KeyboardButton('Other')
    item_5 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
    markup.add(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types="private", func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Random")
def bot_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Add variants')
    item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
    markup.add(item_1, item_2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types="private", func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Add variants")
def func_name(message):
    ...
    # some code
```

Comment: все равно не получается. А вообще возможно сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку добавлялись следующие сообщения пользователя в список?(например человек пишет сообщения, из которых потом бот выбирает рандомно несколько) или это бред и так сделать нельзя?

Comment: @xogeh Простите, но что у вас не получается?

Comment: Не получается добавлять сообщения пользователя в список. Ну то есть он нажимает на кнопку 'Add variants' и последующие сообщения должны добавляться в список.